# Running Command-Line Commands in Gulp

Tags: gulp

Have a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task that I'm trying to create. The task has to do the following:

1. Start my web server
2. Start the selenium server
3. Run my tests

I am able to do these three things manually from the command line. At this time, I open one tab from the terminal window in Mac OS X and I run:

`dnx . run`

That command starts my web server. Then, in another tab in the terminal window, I run:

`java -jar node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar`

That command starts the selenium test server. Then, in a third tab in the terminal window, I run:

`gulp test`

The `gulp test` task is responsible for executing my tests. I would really like `gulp test` to also a) start my web server and b) start the selenium server. Basically, `gulp test` would run through all of my tests *once*, then return to a command prompt. In an attempt to do this, I am using [gulp-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec). I'm not sure if that's the package I should use for this approach. Still, at this time, I have the following:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src('./tests/*.js')
    .pipe(jasmine())
  ;
});
```

The above task successfully executes my tests. However, it only does so *after* the web server and selenium server have been manually started. How do I start the web server, then the selenium server, and then execute the tests in my task with Gulp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The primary, built in, way to accomplish this is through `require('child_process').exec('echo Hello World')`

In addition to that, there are three github / npm projects that accomplish this

1. [gulp-run](https://github.com/MrBoolean/gulp-run)
2. [gulp-spawn](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-spawn)
3. [gulp-shell](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell)